# Cutting of an part from an image - javacv

Tags: javacv

Im kind of new in javacv and hope you can help me with a problem.

I have used rectangle recognition on an image, to find a car license plate. But what I got problem with is that I want to cut out this part of the picture and save it as an new image. How do I do this in javacv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to cut it (getting sub-image), you can just use this (I assume you know the basic in using )

```
private static CvCapture grabber;
private static IplImage temp;
private static BufferedImage buff;

...

temp = cvRetrieveFrame(grabber);
buff = temp.getBufferedImage().getSubimage(areaTop.x, areaTop.y, areaTop.width, areaTop.height);

File f  = new File ("your/filepath.jpg");
ImageIO.write(buff, "jpg", f);
```

if you don't want to save it and just use it directly in memory, you can try to use:

> com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.cvSetImageROI

hope it helps.